# Hadoop Jar runs but no output. Driver, mapper and reduce compiles successfully in namenode

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'm a newbie to Hadoop Programming and I have started learning by setting up Hadoop 2.7.1 on a three node cluster. I have tried running helloworld jars that comes out of the box in Hadoop and it ran fine with success but I wrote my own driver code in my local machine and bundled it into a jar and executed it this way but it fails with NO error messages.

Here is my code and this is what I did.

WordCountMapper.java

```
package mot.com.bin.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;



public class WordCountMapper  extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>

{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text Value,
                        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> opc, Reporter r)
                        throws IOException {
                String s = Value.toString();
                for (String word :s.split(" ")) {
                        if( word.length() > 0) {
                                opc.collect(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
                        }
                }

        }


}
```

WordCountReduce.java

```
package mot.com.bin.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordCountReduce  extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer < Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> opc, Reporter r)
                        throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int i = 0;
                while (values.hasNext()) {
                        IntWritable in = values.next();
                        i+=in.get();
                }
                opc.collect(key, new IntWritable (i));
        }
```

WordCount.java

```
/**
 * **DRIVER**
 */
package mot.com.bin.test;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.Text;

/**
 * @author rgb764
 *
 */
public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool{

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {

                if (arg0.length < 2) {
                        System.out.println("Need input file and output directory");
                        return -1;
                }

                JobConf conf = new JobConf();

                FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path( arg0[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path( arg0[1]));

                conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

                conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
                conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReduce.class);

                conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

                JobClient.runJob(conf);
                return 0;
        }

}
```

First I tried extracting it as a jar from eclipse and run it in my hadoop cluster. No errors yet no success as well. Then moved my individual java files to my NameNode and compiled each java files and then created the jar file there, still hadoop command returns no results but no errors as well. Kindly help me on this.

```
hadoop jar WordCout.jar mot.com.bin.test.WordCount /karthik/mytext.txt /tempo
```

Extracted all dependent jar files using Maven and I added them into the classpath in my name node. Help me figure what and where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you are missing the code in your main method which instantiate the Tool implementation  ( WordCount in your case) and runs the same.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
           int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(), args);         
           System.exit(res);
   }
```

Refer [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html).